# php date() mysql datetime

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, date

I want to use PHP to insert date into mysql datetime field.

```
$time = date('Y-m-d');

mysql_query(INSERT INTO A (date) VALUE ('$time'));
```

Table A date column is datetime field. I want it shows 2011-01-24. But it always shows 2011-01-24 00:00:00. So my problem is how to remove the suffix "00:00:00".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the field is a `DATETIME` field, it stores the `DATE` and the `TIME`. If you want to exclusively store the date, make it a `DATE` field.

Answer (score 1):

Change the column type to DATE instead of datetime!

Answer (score 1):

A bit unclear, I see 2 possible solutions:

If you're referring to removing the suffix 00:00:00 from the MySQL, you need to change the field type from datetime into a date.

If you're referring to the removal of the suffix from the php script, well you can always use

```
mysql_query(SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d-%m-%Y') FROM a);
```

read up [mysql date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: `SELECT DATE(date) FROM a;` would work just as well, it's basically an alias to the date_format call, and is somewhat more readable.

Comment: true that :p it's a habit I guess :p

Answer (score 1):

Change the field to a DATE field in your table. Your PHP code is fine as it is.